# Inserting string in mysql using python: unknown column

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

first of all i am a beginner, and i appreciate the help in advance :)

When i am inserting a string it is giving me an error double or single quotes.This only happens when im calling the function insert() i have created. But when i am just putting a number in replace of those strings without quotation marks it is working.

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="root",password='password',
       host='localhost',database='library',port='3306')
cur = conn.cursor()


def create_table():
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store 
               (id INT PRIMARY KEY, item VARCHAR(25), quantity INT, price REAL);")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def insert(id, item, quantity, price):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO store (id, quantity, price, item) 
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)" % (id, item, quantity, price))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()



insert(50, 'test', 20, 10)
```

and then it is giving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 392, in cmd_query
        raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
    _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Remastered.py", line 128, in <module>
        insert(50, 'test', 20, 10)
      File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Remastered.py", line 109, in insert
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO store (id, quantity, price, item) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)" % (id, item, quantity, price))
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
        raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 395, in cmd_query
        sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
    mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'
    [Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Don’t concatenate/format SQL strings, use parameters. It will fix this and many other possible problems. As for what the actual problem is I suggest you print out the SQL query you are sending to the database. It will show what is wrong with this way of doing things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the placeholder feature properly. The correct line is:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO store (id, quantity, price, item) 
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (id, item, quantity, price))
```

Note `,` and **NOT** `%` which creates serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Your query was being expanded to something like:

```
INSERT INTO store (...) VALUES (1, test, 1, 1.0);
```

Where the `test` part is not quoted at all and is treated as a possible column name.

Comment: thanks, but how can i call the insert function, if i put the test without the quotation it will just say test is not defined?

Comment: I just explained how to use `execute` properly. The first argument is the statement with `%s` placeholder values. The second part is a tuple with the values you're inserting. Your mistake was using string interpolation with `printf` style interpretation, which doesn't escape or quote. The `execute` statement packages up the query and values in a form that can be sent over the MySQL binary connection properly, no escaping required usually, or if there is then it's applied correctly and consistently.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the order of columns in the insert statement, change "INSERT INTO store (id, quantity, price, item)" to "INSERT INTO store (id, item, quantity, price)", note where column named item is!
    import mysql.connector

```
def create_table():
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store " \
           "(id INT PRIMARY KEY, item VARCHAR(25), quantity INT, price REAL);")
  conn.commit()
  return

def insert(id, item, quantity, price):
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO store (id, item, quantity, price)" \
            "VALUES (%s, '%s', %s, %s)" % (id, item, quantity, price))
  conn.commit()
  return

#
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="root",
   host='localhost',database='DO',port='3306')
cur = conn.cursor()

create_table
insert(50, 'test', 20, 10)
insert(51, 'test', 20, 10)
insert(52, 'test', 20, 10)
conn.close()
```

from MySQL

```
mysql> select * from store;
+----+------+----------+-------+
| id | item | quantity | price |
+----+------+----------+-------+
| 50 | test |       20 |    10 |
| 51 | test |       20 |    10 |
| 52 | test |       20 |    10 |
+----+------+----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  INSERT INTO store (id, item, quantity, price) VALUES (53, 'test', 20, 10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from store;
+----+------+----------+-------+
| id | item | quantity | price |
+----+------+----------+-------+
| 50 | test |       20 |    10 |
| 51 | test |       20 |    10 |
| 52 | test |       20 |    10 |
| 53 | test |       20 |    10 |
+----+------+----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Also note the quotes around %s for "item" in the INSERT statement:   
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO store (id, item, quantity, price)" \
            "VALUES (%s, '%s', %s, %s)" % (id, item, quantity, price))